# How to access nested Json Object Value into JPA Entity Class

Tags: json, spring, jpa, java-8, payload

I have a payload like this

```json
{
    "eventId":"ep9_0579af51",
    "eventTime":"5/11/2022 5:50:58 PM",
    "eventType":"UpdateTransaction",
    "meta":{
        "userId":"vkp",
        "resourceType":"Transaction/DataDocs"
    }
}
```

I need to map this json fields into a single entity class .

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/id", consumes = "application/json") 
public ResponseEntity<ImportTrans> import(@RequestBody ImportTrans importTrans) {
    return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.ofNullable(repository.save(importTrans););
}
```

```java
@Table(name = "IMPORT_TRANS")
@Entity
public class ImportTrans implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long processId;// AutoGenerator
    private String eventId;
    private Date eventTime;
    private String eventType;

    private String userId; // I dont want create new class for meta . Is there any way i 
    //can access meta.userId in ImportTrans class.
    private String resourceType;
}
```

How can I access data from `meta` from `ImportTrans` without creating a separate class for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your request body before reaching the controller.

> "You must consider the application performance factors on your own
> before implementation"

Option 1. Using RequestBodyAdvice.

Option 2. Using Spring HandlerInterceptor.

Option 3. Use AOP

Option 4. Using HTTP Filter.

---

The below solution only works if you are using a separate DTO class.

```
private Map<String, String> meta = new HashMap<>();

String userID = importTrans.getMeta().get("userId");
```

I hope the above pieces of information answered your question.

Comment: importTrans is my Entity Class  . I have to map it directly from Controller

Comment: If importTrans is your Entity class, what about "meta"? is it your column? Do you want to persist "meta"? You should add such kind of information to your question.

Comment: As you can see meta is a nested portion in json , i want to get the userId and resourceType from meta into my importTrans entity class . I am not writing any mapping , it has to map through requestBody (@RequestBody ImportTrans importTrans))

Comment: Answer modified, please try.